# Store global variable out of shell script

Tags: linux, unix, raspbian

I have a shell script with the following problem:
Each time I execute the script again, the variable CURRENT gets set to 0 again, but how can I make it that CURRENT gets saved after each script execution?

```
#!/bin/sh
CURRENT=0
A='Knight rider'
B='Full color mood blobs'
C='Police Lights Single'
D='Police Lights Solid'
E='Rainbow mood'
F='Rainbow swirl'
G='Rainbow swirl fast'
H='Snake'
I='Strobe blue'

case $CURRENT in
    0) hyperion-remote --effect "$A"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    1) hyperion-remote --effect "$B"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    2) hyperion-remote --effect "$C"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    3) hyperion-remote --effect "$D"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    4) hyperion-remote --effect "$E"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    5) hyperion-remote --effect "$F"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    6) hyperion-remote --effect "$G"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    7) hyperion-remote --effect "$H"; CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT + 1 ));;
    8) hyperion-remote --effect "$I"; CURRENT=0;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variable.

```
if [ -z "$CURRENT" ]; then
    CURRENT=0;
    export CURRENT;
else
    CURRENT=$CURRENT;
fi
```

Do not forget to update $CURRENT at the end of the script.